# Auto Run SSIS package when a file is changed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, automation

I am sure this is possible but I cant seem to locate any documentation from any of my training on how.

Is there a way to develop an SSIS package that will automatically run and update my tables whenever there is a change registered to a specific file.

For example, I have an Excel Spreadsheet that is updated by accounting. I am building a package that will grab the data from the spreadsheet and place it in a table to be consumed by other processes.

The data is updated very infrequently though and I have to manually run the package after a specific date because the Accounting Department cant get the data into the spreadsheet on time.

I hope that I am not crazy but I believe I have heard of this capability before.

Comment: See if the `WMI Event Watcher Task` helps you. But you might be better off just scheduling the package to run every 5 minutes and check that way as I doubt you need an instantaneous update. Also be aware that if the file is open when you try to read it it will probably throw an error

Answer (score 2):

You could write a service like this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv) and have the service execute the package via DTexec.

Comment: Very cool, I'll need to look into this more. Not strong with C# but this sums it up pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's such feature, you may consider to develop a package SSIS than runs every 1min for exemple to get the last modification date and compare it with a value that you may keep somewhee (File, table) and run the package SSIS if the two values are different.
Make sure that the file is on mode erad write using a task script before loading the data in your SSIS package.
I hope this will help you.